# valid mysql query returns error when executed via mysql_query(...)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have following PHP code:

```
$result = mysql_query('
            set @num := 0, @type := "";
            UPDATE orders INNER JOIN (
                SELECT id, user_id, created, row_number 
                FROM 
                (
                    SELECT id, user_id, created,
                    @num := if(@type = user_id, @num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
                    @type := user_id AS dummy
                    FROM orders
                    WHERE status = "queue" AND type="order"
                    ORDER BY user_id, created asc 
                ) AS grouped_orders 
                WHERE grouped_orders.row_number <= 2
            ) m ON orders.id = m.id 
            SET orders.status = "process", orders.lock_id = "hash";
        ');
```

When I skip `$result = mysql_query('` and `');` and copy-paste this query to my PHP MyAdmin panel it works - but when I execute it with mysql_query(...) from PHP I get following error:

`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE orders INNER JOIN (
                                SELECT id, user_id, created, row_number
                                FROM' at line 2`

I tried to do something with brackets, movig up/down and collapsing to one line but it doesnt work...

Unfortunately on server I am working on there is no mysqli.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$result = mysql_query('
            set @num := 0, @type := "";
            UPDATE orders INNER JOIN (
                SELECT id, user_id, created, row_number 
                FROM 
                (
                    SELECT id, user_id, created,
                    @num := if(@type = user_id, @num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
                    @type := user_id AS dummy
                    FROM orders
                    WHERE status = "queue" AND type="order"
                    ORDER BY user_id, created asc 
                ) AS grouped_orders 
                WHERE grouped_orders.row_number <= 2
            ) m ON orders.id = grouped_orders.id 
            SET orders.status = "process", orders.lock_id = "hash";
        ');
```

the group order is the name of the second table to join

EDIT:

Your query looks to be O.K (at least there is no error), however your problem rely in PHP you are using mysql_query.

"mysql_query() sends a unique query (multiple queries are not supported) to the currently active database on the server that's associated with the specified link_identifier. " (http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

So you need another way to execute multi queries, or find another solution, try to force to use the mysqli because you'll prevent attacks too and will be able to multi queries....

Comment: can you upload part of the tables to sqlfiddle, it would be a lot better to help you: sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 0):

try [multi-query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) instead of `mysql_query` since you are executing more that one query

### Edit

Try defining your variables in your select due subselects:

```
UPDATE orders INNER JOIN (
      SELECT id, user_id, created, row_number 
      FROM 
      (
           SELECT id, user_id, created,
           @num := if(@type = user_id, @num + 1, 1) AS row_number,
           @type := user_id AS dummy
           FROM orders
           WHERE status = "queue" AND type="order"
           ORDER BY user_id, created asc 
            ) AS grouped_orders, (SELECT @num:=0) r, (SELECT @type:="") t
            WHERE grouped_orders.row_number <= 2
        ) m ON orders.id = grouped_orders.id 
        SET orders.status = "process", orders.lock_id = "hash";
```

Comment: Then I would have to rewrite whole app to use mysqli - is there any workaround?